# Evaluate the limit $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty } \root n \of {{a_k}{n^k} + {a_{k - 1}}{n^{k - 1}} + ... + {a_0}} $

Tags: calculus, limits

> Evaluate the limit $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty } \root n \of {{a_k}{n^k} + {a_{k - 1}}{n^{k - 1}} + ... + {a_0}} $
>   $a_0,...a_k > 0$

Is the following right?

for $n$ sufficiently large:
$$1 = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \root n \of {{a_k}{n^k}}  \le \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \root n \of {{a_k}{n^k} + {a_{k - 1}}{n^{k - 1}} + ... + {a_0}}  \le \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \root n \of {k \cdot {a_k}{n^k}}  = 1$$

Comment: The general idea is good. On the right, we want to replace $a_k$ by the max of the $a_i$. And there are $k+1$ terms. You should write the inequalities without limits, and then take limits.

Comment: Without knowing what the  relation between the coefficients $\;a_k\;$ is both inequalities may be pretty wrong...

Comment: @DonAntonio, Can you explain? I did mention "for sufficiently large $n$".

Comment: $n$ need not be large to set up inequalities, the $a_i$ are positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good to me: the key is that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} n^{1/n}=1$. You might be more explicit about how large $n$ needs to be.